# Change filename of Excel-files based on the content of a cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, file-system

I have hundreds of Excel-sheets looking something like this:

[image]

<sub>I can't use the actual sheet, and not the exact document numbers, since they are confidential.</sub>

---

The name of the files are something like

```
2301 Item 1.xlsx
2014 Item 2.xlsx
5321 Item 3.xlsx
3212 Item 200.xlsx
```

I want to change the names of these files, based on the document name that's given in cell **C5** in each Excel-sheet. Note: the cells **C5 - E5** are merged.

---

I've written the following Python 3 script:

```
import os
import xlrd

def rename_excel_files():

    path = r"C:\Users\Stewie\Documents\excel_folder\\"

    for filename in os.listdir(path):

        excel_file = xlrd.open_workbook(path + filename)
        work_sheet = excel_file.sheet_by_index(0)
        new_filename = work_sheet.cell_value(4,2)
        os.rename(path + '\\' + filename, path + new_filename + '.xlsx')

rename_excel_files()
```

It works perfectly fine... But I guess it's not perfect..?

Any tips?

---

Note, this finishes almost instantly, so I don't really want to improve the execution time if that results in code that's harder to read, write and understand.

Also note: It's always cell **C5**. I don't need the cell-number to be dynamic. This is a fixed template that's used on literally thousands of files. I will only use it on the files on that template.

Answer (score 3):

The good practice is to finish your code with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     sys.exit(main())
```

which has the advantage of returning an error code to the system (for example for batch processing of related programs).

It means 3 things for changing your code:

1. `import sys`
2. moving your command `rename_excel_files(r"C:\Users\Stewie\Documents\excel_folder")` to the new created `main()` function.
3. adding an `return` statement to the `main()` function with value `0` in the case of the success (and optionally something else for the failure):

So the result will be something as

```
import os
import sys
import xlrd
    ...
    ...
    ...

def main():
    rename_excel_files(r"C:\Users\Stewie\Documents\excel_folder")
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

(See "3.3.1 Use sys.exit in your script to return proper error codes" in the book [Writing Idiomatic Python by Jeff Knupp, 2013](https://jeffknupp.com/writing-idiomatic-python-ebook/) - or directly from our BDFL - in [All Things Pythonic - Python main() functions by Guido van van Rossum
May 15, 2003](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829))

Comment: Could you link to the source where it's specified that what you suggested is a _good practice_? IMO it kinda' looks verbose and unnecessary and I've never read anywhere about it :)

Comment: @MrGrj thanks for your comment - I added some links at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hardcoding the path to the files to be renamed, I would use a parameter. This will let you expand the script to allow to pass that path on the command-line or via a GUI or whatever later.

I would also use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of manually concatenating the path, the intent feels cleaner.

Lastly, an [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard would allow you to import that file without executing any logic:

```
import os
import xlrd


def rename_excel_files(path):
    """TODO: add a docstring here"""

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        excel_file = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath)
        work_sheet = excel_file.sheet_by_index(0)
        new_filename = work_sheet.cell_value(4,2)
        os.rename(filepath, os.path.join(path, new_filename + '.xlsx'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rename_excel_files(r'C:\Users\Stewie\Documents\excel_folder')
```

Answer (score 1):

- [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) could raise `OSError` if the destination directory already exists on Windows. So, perhaps you want to handle that. Or you could use [`os.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace) to get cross-platform destination file overriding.
- You should group standard library and third party imports separately.
- If you're on Python 3.4+ you could also use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

import xlrd


def rename_excel_files(path):
    path = Path(path)

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        file_path = path.joinpath(filename)
        excel_file = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
        work_sheet = excel_file.sheet_by_index(0)
        dest_path = path.joinpath(work_sheet.cell_value(4, 2) + '.xlsx')
        os.replace(file_path, dest_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     rename_excel_files(r"C:\Users\Stewie\Documents\excel_folder")
```

Comment: I think `os.replace(file_path, dest_path)` could be replaced with `file_path.replace(dest_path)`.