# Guess the computer's number using functions

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, number-guessing-game

I am looking to improve the Python Number Guessing Game program:

1. How is the overall structure of the code?
2. Have I used functions to the best of their ability?
3. Can the code be simplified? If yes, please feel free to show how.
4. The `replay_game()` function especially seems un-pythonic and overkill.

```
# Guess My Number Game
# MacOSX (Latest), Python 3.4.3, 27/08/2017
# Guess The Computers number between 1-100

from random import randint
from time import sleep

def gen_number():
    random_number = randint(0, 101)
    return random_number

def intro():
    print("Welcome to, Guess My Number!")
    print("Simply guess the number between 1-100 that the Computer is 'thinking' of!")
    print()

def ask_number(question, random_number):
    response = None
    while response != random_number:
        try:
            response = int(input(question))
            if response > random_number:
                print("Lower... ")
            elif response < random_number:
                print("Higher... ")
            else:
                correct = response
                congrat_winner(correct, random_number)
        except ValueError:
                print("Invalid. Enter a number between 1-100 ")
    return response

def human_guess():
    print("Ok Human! Let's begin... ")
    sleep(1)
    random_number = gen_number() # Named the variable random_number, the same as the variable in gen_number(). Is this good practise?
    guess = ask_number("Guess the number: ", random_number)

def congrat_winner(correct, random_number):
    if correct == random_number:
        print()
        print("Calculating results...")
        sleep(1)
        print()
        print("WELL DONE!")
        print("The answer was indeed,", str(correct) + "!")

def replay_game():
    replay_question = None
    while replay_question != 'y' or 'n':
        replay_question = input("Would you like to play again (y/n)? ").lower()
        if replay_question == 'y':
            print()
            print("Rebuilding game... ")
            main()
        elif replay_question == 'n':
            print("Goodbye!")
            exit()
        else:
            print("please enter either 'y' or 'n'... ")

def main():
    intro()
    human_guess()
    replay_game()

main()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [classic problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902492/python-testing-whether-a-string-is-one-of-a-certain-set-of-values) in this condition:

```
while replay_question != 'y' or 'n':
```

It always evaluates to `True` since string `n` is always truthy.

And, here is a set of code style violations I would work on:

- `guess` variable inside the `human_guess()` function is *unused*
- keep 2 blank lines between the function definition ([PEP 8 - Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines))
- put the `main()` function call into under the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)
- the `print("Invalid. Enter a number between 1-100 ")` is overly indented with 8 spaces, use 4 spaces
- you can use a *multi-line string* for your `intro` message:

  ```
  print("""
  Welcome to, Guess My Number!
  Simply guess the number between 1-100 that the Computer is 'thinking' of!
  """)
  ```

Comment: `while replay_question not in ('y', 'n'):`

Comment: Hi there, many thanks for your answer. Was the while loop in replay_question just comparing two string types instead of the content of the strings?

Comment: @Greg If you split up the conditional, you get `replay_question != 'y'` and `'n'`. Since non-empty strings in Python are always truthy, this condition always evaluates to true.

Comment: @lyricLy Brilliant, thank you for confirming. Greg.

Answer (score 8):

Just some notes:

---

The bug:

```
random_number = randint(0, 101)
```

returns integers from `0` to `101`, *including* both `0` and `101`. The fix:

```
random_number = randint(1, 100)
```

(but see the next note).

---

The [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47888/7023590) `1` and `100`, moreover repeatedly used. You may define them as constants near the top of your code, e. g.

```
LOWER_LIMIT = 1
UPPER_LIMIT = 100
```

and then use them in these (inconsecutive) lines of your code:

```
random_number = randint(0, 101)

print("Simply guess the number between 1-100 that the Computer is 'thinking' of!")

print("Invalid. Enter a number between 1-100 ")
```

changing them to

```
random_number = randint(LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT)     # see fix in the first note

print("Simply guess the number between {}-{} that the Computer is 'thinking' of!"
      .format(LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT))

print("Invalid. Enter a number between {}-{} "
      .format(LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT))
```

( `{}` in strings are replacement fields for parameters in the `.format()` method.)

Comment: Wow! I haven't been exposed to this sort of formatting before in Python. I really like this. Thank you for pointing it out. In addition, it is far easier to understand when you used the constant variables. Out of interest, do you think I could have put the main() function to better use? Thank you. Greg

Comment: We still learn something new. In Python 3.6+ is even possible to write it more straighforward, without `.format()` method, with the `f` string's prefix  and expressions directly in the replacement fields `{}`- `print(f"Invalid. Enter a number between {LOWER_LIMIT}-{UPPER_LIMIT} ")`

Comment: It's definitely better to use the `main()` function - see the last (3rd) part of my [another answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173931/change-filename-of-excel-files-based-on-the-content-of-a-cell/173951#173951) with the links for reasoning such practice.

Answer (score 4):

Your answers (Lower... or Higher... ) are ambiguous - is the answer (guess) lower or is such the unknown number?

Maybe something as "Try lower ..." would be more appropriate.

---

In your `congrat_winner()` function

```
def congrat_winner(correct, random_number):
    if correct == random_number:
        print()
        print("Calculating results...")
        sleep(1)
        print()
        print("WELL DONE!")
        print("The answer was indeed,", str(correct) + "!")
```

is the introductory testing superfluous (and - consequently - the second parameter is needless) as you call that function only after passing the similar test.

So your function may be shortened to

```
def congrat_winner(correct):
    print()
    print("Calculating results...")
    sleep(1)
    print()
    print("WELL DONE!")
    print("The answer was indeed,", str(correct) + "!")
```

Subsequently, the part

```
        else:
            correct = response
            congrat_winner(correct, random_number)
```

where you call that function have to be changed to

```
        else:
            congrat_winner(response)      # directly used 'response' instead of 'correct'
```

(There is no more reason for the `correct = response` statement.)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your feedback. Yes, the if statement in congrat_winner() was useless. Would it be simpler to call the congrat_winner function through human_guess by using the guess variable? Thank you.

Comment: No, it isn't possible as `guess` is only a *local* variable of the `human_guess`, btw. **never used** so you may simply omit it. To be clear I am going to write another answer about it.

Answer (score 4):

I would replace `random_number = gen_number()` with `randint(0, 101)`.

`randint` is already a function. What is the use in wrapping it in another function which does nothing extra?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question to show improved code.

Answer (score 4):

In the loop where you take input you have the following statement:

```
    try:
        response = int(input(question))
        if response > random_number:
            print("Lower... ")
        elif response < random_number:
            print("Higher... ")
        else:
            correct = response
            congrat_winner(correct, random_number)
    except ValueError:
            print("Invalid. Enter a number between 1-100 ")
```

If the input is not numeric, you return `Invalid. Enter a number between 1-100`, but not when your input is outside of the `1-100` range. You might want to add a check for that as well:

```
    try:
        response = int(input(question))
        if response not in range(1, 101):
            print("Invalid. Enter a number between 1-100 ")
        elif response > random_number:
            print("Lower... ")
        elif response < random_number:
            print("Higher... ")
        else:
            correct = response
            congrat_winner(correct, random_number)
    except ValueError:
            print("Invalid. Enter a number between 1-100 ")
```

Comment: Hi - thank you, I just spotted this - I have added the new code in the question section above. Greg.

Answer (score 1):

In the last line of your `human_guess()` function

```
    guess = ask_number("Guess the number: ", random_number)
```

you assign the return value of the function `ask_number()` to a local variable `guess` which is not accessible from outside of the `human_guess()` function, so it may be omitted.

So that statement will become just:

```
ask_number("Guess the number: ", random_number)
```

Consequently your `ask_number()` function need not return anything so the last line in its definition

```
    return response
```

may be safely deleted, too.

Comment: Great - thank you. I have taken your advice onboard and have updated the code accordingly in the question section.

Answer (score 0):

I have collated and considered all the fantastic answers above and greated the following program. I hope this is of significant use.

```
# Guess My Number Game
# MacOSX (Latest), Python 3.4.3, 28/08/2017
# Guess the Computers number between 1-100

from random import randint
from time import sleep
import sys

LOWER_LIMIT = 1
UPPER_LIMIT = 100

def intro():
    print("""
    Welcome to, Guess My Number!
    Simply guess the number between {}-{} that the Computer is 'thinking' of!
    You will have the option of replaying the game. First, guess the number!

    Ok Human, let's begin... """
    .format(LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT
            ))
    sleep(1)


def ask_number(question, random_number):
    response = None
    while response != random_number:
        try:
            response = int(input(question))
            if response not in range(LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT):
                print("Invalid. Enter a number between {}-{} "
                      .format(LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT))
            elif response < random_number:
                print("Try Higher... ")
            elif response > random_number:
                print("Try Lower... ")
            else:
                congrat_winner(response)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid. Enter a number between {}-{} "
                  .format(LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT))


def human_guess():
    random_number = randint(LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT)
    ask_number("Guess the number: ", random_number)


def congrat_winner(winning_guess):
    print()
    print("Calculating results...")
    sleep(1)
    print("CONGRATULATIONS")
    print("The answer was indeed,", str(winning_guess) + "!")


def replay_game():
    replay_question = None
    while replay_question not in ('y', 'n'):
        replay_question = input("Would you like to play again (y/n)? ").lower()
        if replay_question == 'y':
            print("Rebuilding game... ")
            sleep(1)
            main()
        elif replay_question == 'n':
            print("Goodbye... ")
            break
        else:
            print("please enter either 'y' or 'n'... ")


def main():
    intro()
    print()
    human_guess()
    print()
    replay_game()
    print()
    return 0 

if __name__ == '__main__':
     sys.exit(main())
```