# Duplicating Excel-workbook, and transferring data

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, file-system

<sub>This is a follow up to the simpler [question here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/173931/109032).</sub>

I have hundreds of files looking something like this:

[image]

These files have names such as:

```
2301 Item 1.xlsx
2014 Item 2.xlsx
5321 Item 3.xlsx
3212 Item 200.xlsx
```

I also have a template file (`Template.xlsx`) looking like this:

[image]

I want to:

- Copy the template file, and for each of the other files

  - Give it the filename in cell **C6**.
  - Copy the values of **B2,B3,B3** over to the appropriate spot in the template (**B4,B5,B6**).
  - Copy the filename to **B8**

I've written the following script in Python 3:

```
import os
import shutil

from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

def duplicate_and_transfer(path):

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename == 'Template.xlsx':
            continue
        else:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            excel_file = open_workbook(filepath)
            worksheet = excel_file.sheet_by_index(0)
            new_filename = worksheet.cell_value(5,2)
            new_filepath = os.path.join(path, new_filename + '.xls')
            r_value = [0,0,0]
            for row in range(3):
                r_value[row] = worksheet.cell_value(row+1,1)    


            shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, 'Template.xlsx'),new_filepath)
            rb = open_workbook(new_filepath)
            wb = copy(rb)
            s = wb.get_sheet(0)
            s.write(7,2,new_filename)
            for r in range(3):
                s.write(r+3,1,r_value[r])

            wb.save(new_filepath)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    duplicate_and_transfer(r'C:\Users\Stewie\Documents\excel_folder')
```

---

A few things:

- I have to make the new files `xls` instead of `xlsx`. They get corrupted if not ([someone else have had this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957831/edit-existing-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-with-xlrd-and-xlwt#comment45427579_26958437)). Can I avoid this?
- Should I split this up into more functions?

This is fast enough, so my main issue is not with performance.

Answer (score 2):

- Since you use `continue` in the `if` clause, you can get rid of the `else` part and save a level of indentation.
- You can use a list-comprehension to build the list of `r_value`: `[worksheet.cell_value(row + 1, 1) for row in range(3)]`.
- You can iterate directly over the content of `r_value` to set it back:

  ```
  for row, value in enumerate(r_value, 3):
      s.write(row, 1, value)
  ```
- I don't think you need to copy the template first and modify it after. You may be able to open the template and then save it using the new filename.
- You can use a second parameter with a default value to hold the name of the template.

Proposed improvements:

```
import os

from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy


def duplicate_and_transfer(path, template_name='Template.xlsx'):
    template = os.path.join(path, template_name)

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename == template_name:
            continue

        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        excel_file = open_workbook(filepath)
        worksheet = excel_file.sheet_by_index(0)
        new_filename = worksheet.cell_value(5,2)
        new_filepath = os.path.join(path, new_filename + '.xls')
        values = [worksheet.cell_value(row + 1, 1) for row in range(3)]

        rb = open_workbook(template)
        workbook = copy(rb)
        worksheet = workbook.get_sheet(0)
        worksheet.write(7, 2, new_filename)
        for row, value in enumerate(values, 3):
            worksheet.write(row, 1, value)

        workbook.save(new_filepath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    duplicate_and_transfer(r'C:\Users\Stewie\Documents\excel_folder')
```

You may as well be able to open the template once and save it several times.

Lastly, if you have troubles working with XLSX files, you may want to try [`openpyxl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) instead:

```
import os

from openpyxl import load_workbook


def duplicate_and_transfer(path, template_name='Template.xlsx'):
    template = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, template_name))

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename == template_name:
            continue

        workbook = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, filename))
        worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]

        new_filename = worksheet['C6'].value
        template['B8'] = new_filename
        new_filepath = os.path.join(path, new_filename + '.xlsx')

        # Using double unpacking as the ranges will return a 3-tuple of 1-tuple
        for (src,), (dest,) in zip(worksheet['B2:B4'], template['B4:B6']):
            dest.value = src.value

        template.save(new_filepath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    duplicate_and_transfer(r'C:\Users\Stewie\Documents\excel_folder')
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias! I tried using `openpyxl` and got the following error (my SO post): https://stackoverflow.com/q/46150893/2338750. Do you know what might have caused this?